# How to pass an instance of a custom component to next screen in React native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am creating a custom component in React native and modifying its properties, and I would like to pass this component to the next screen so that I can access the properties. This is my code so far:

```
import Metronome2 from './src/newMetronomeRN.tsx';


function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Metronome2></Metronome2>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Record')}>  
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}> RECORD </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      
    </View>
  );
}
```

I would like to pass the instance of Metronome2 that is created to be passed to the next screen when 'Record' is pressed. If I could get any advice on how to accomplish this it would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Here is the way I am handling the navigation and my next screen:

```
function DetailsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <CameraApp/>
    </View>
    
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Metronome">
        <Stack.Screen name="Metronome" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Record" component={DetailsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What is the next screen? Please show that component. Also show how you are handling navigation. Are you using `react-router` or a similar library?

Comment: You can import Metronome2 instance as you do inside the HomeScreen. If Metronome2 instance inside the HomeScreen has stateful logic and you want to keep the same state inside the Record screen, it would be better to pass state information using route params. You can check React Navigation docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/. Btw, further information needed to reply your question correctly.

Comment: @TunahanBayındır You are correct that it is best to pass the state as route parameters. This isn't the same as passing the same instance like the OP asks, though. And `import Metronome2` imports the class with this name; it doesn't import a specific instance of that class.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I am trying to do but how do I access the state information from the instance of Metronome2?